# How does feature selection work in Random Forest?

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest, cart

I've been trying to improve the performance of my random forest model, and read the following paper on feature selection using random forest (see algorithm in section IV: Overfitting - A. Feature Selection):

http://ftp.cs.nyu.edu/mishra/PUBLICATIONS/Heritage11.pdf

My understanding is, suppose there are 5 predictors: [A, B, C, D, E], the algorithm does the following:

1. run_random_forest(data=[A, B, C, D, E], max_features=5) => OOB=0.5, least_important_feature = [B]
2. delete [B] from the data file
3. run_random_forest(data=[A, C, D, E], max_features=4) => OOB=0.6,
   least_important_feature = [C]
4. delete [C] from the data file
5. run_random_forest(data=[A, D, E], max_features=3) => OOB=0.5,
   least_important_feature = [A]
6. Since OOB score in step 5 is smaller than OOB score in step 3, the "optimal"    max_features is 4
7. run_random_forest(data=[A, B, C, D, E], max_features=4), and rank
   the feature importance.

Here I have 2 questions:

1) Am I understanding the algorithm correctly?

2) What happens after step 7? If the rank of feature importance after step 7 is D>E>C>B>A with max_features=4, do we then:

- delete feature [A] forever from the data file, and only train the random forest with run_random_forest(data=[B, C, D, E], max_features=4), and predict with [B, C, D, E]?
- or do we still keep feature [A] from the data file, and train the random forest with run_random_forest(data=[A, B, C, D, E], max_feature=4), and predict with [A, B, C, D, E]?
  Help is really appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Best Regards,

mangoengineer

Comment: The link is dead...

Answer (score 3):

Hope [this](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b88052/tmp/vietri.pdf) will help (the section 2 of the paper)

"Variable Selection in Random Forest with Application to Quantitative Structure-Activity Relationship", Vladimir Svetnik, Andy Liaw, and Christopher Tong, *Biometrics Research*

Comment: great answer. I only know https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#varimp, which is a simplified version.